# Remove blank key entries in Pandas pd.to_dict

Tags: pandas, dictionary

Pandas has a very nice feature to export our dataframes to a list of dicts via `pd.to_dict('records')`.

For example:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':['a', 'b', None]}) 
d.to_dict('records')
```

returns

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 'a'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'b'}, {'a': 3, 'b': None}]
```

For my use case, I would prefer the following entry:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 'a'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'b'}, {'a': 3}]
```

where you can see the key of `b` is removed from the third entry.  This is default behavior in R when using `jsonlite`, and am wondering how I would remove keys with missing values from each entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: using list comprehension and `itertuples` with nested dict comprehension. It is the fastest

```
l = [{k: v for k, v in tup._asdict().items() if v is not None} 
                                       for tup in d.itertuples(index=False)]

Out[74]: [{'a': 1, 'b': 'a'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'b'}, {'a': 3}]
```

Timing:

```
d1 = pd.concat([d]*5000, ignore_index=True)

In [76]: %timeit [{k: v for k, v in tup._asdict().items() if v is not None} for
    ...:  tup in d1.itertuples(index=False)]
442 ms ± 28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

Another way is using list comprehension and `iterrows`

```
l = [row.dropna().to_dict() for k, row in d.iterrows()]

Out[33]: [{'a': 1, 'b': 'a'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'b'}, {'a': 3}]
```

`iterrows` has reputation of slow performance. I tested on sample of 15000 rows to compare against `stack`

```
In [49]: d1 = pd.concat([d]*5000, ignore_index=True)

In [50]: %timeit d1.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x : x.reset_index(level
    ...: =0,drop=True).to_dict()).tolist()
7.52 s ± 370 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [51]: %timeit [row.dropna().to_dict() for k, row in d1.iterrows()]
6.45 s ± 60.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Interesting result. However, I think if the data is bigger, it will be slower than `stack`

Comment: Wow, amazing stuff here.

Answer (score 3):

We can do `stack`

```
l=d.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x : x.reset_index(level=0,drop=True).to_dict()).tolist()
Out[142]: [{'a': 1, 'b': 'a'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'b'}, {'a': 3}]
```

Comment: Interesting, I don't often think about using `stack`

Answer (score 2):

Dump everything into a dictionary, it should be faster, and easier with a list comprehension :

```
[{key:value
 for key,value in entry.items() 
if value is not None}
 for entry in d.to_dict('records')]


[{'a': 1, 'b': 'a'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'b'}, {'a': 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach (if performance is not an issue) with `apply` and `series.dropna()`

```
d.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict(),axis=1).tolist()
```

---

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 'a'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'b'}, {'a': 3}]
```